# Move message from Dead Letter queue to Outgoing queue MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I have some messages in the system dead letter queue. I want to move it to the outgoing queue. But even though I am an admin on the box , I am unable to do so. I also tried using a tool by the name queue explorer but was unable to do so. Is there a way out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write something on your own to resend the messages.  You should be able to address the queue just like any other such as: @"formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\system$;DeadXact"; PowerShell could do the trick.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, can someone please explain what is 'formatname' in the given command?

Answer (score 7):

This is easily done with QueueExplorer.

Open QueueExplorer and view the dead letter queue where the dead letter messages are (we will call this SERVER A). Sort by destination queue to make this easy.

Open another copy of QueueExplorer, to the server where the queues you wish to move the dead letter entries to are located (SERVER B).

In the first QueueExplorer window, select all the files for X destination (SERVER A). Then, simply drag these into the queue they are supposed to go to in the other QueueExplorer window you opened (SERVER B). This is the easiest way to move stuff from the Dead Letter queue to the correct queue without doing it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Adam is right.
The outgoing queue is not one that you can write to. 
Similarly you cannot create an outgoing queue yourself.
MSMQ dynamically creates an outgoing queue so it can deliver messages you have addressed for a remote queue - basically on demand.

The steps are:
1 read message A from DLQ (as Adam advises)
2 create new message B uses properties from message A
3 send message B to destination of your choice.

Cheers
John Breakwell